# Understanding matplotlib: plt, figure, ax(arr)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I'm not really new to `matplotlib` and I'm deeply ashamed to admit I have always used it as a tool for getting a solution as quick and easy as possible. So I know how to get basic plots, subplots and stuff and have quite a few code which gets reused from time to time...but I have no "deep(er) knowledge" of `matplotlib`.

Recently I thought I should change this and work myself through some tutorials. However, I am still confused about matplotlibs `plt`, `fig(ure)` and `ax(arr)`. What is really the difference?

In most cases, for some "quick'n'dirty' plotting I see people using just `pyplot as plt` and directly plot with `plt.plot`. Since I am having multiple stuff to plot quite often, I frequently use `f, axarr = plt.subplots()`...but most times you see only code putting data into the `axarr` and ignoring the figure `f`.

So, my question is: what is a clean way to work with matplotlib? When to use `plt` only, what is or what should a `figure` be used for? Should subplots just containing data? Or is it valid and good practice to everything like styling, clearing a plot, ..., inside of subplots?

I hope this is not to wide-ranging. Basically I am asking for some advice for the true purposes of `plt` <-> `fig` <-> `ax(arr)` (and when/how to use them properly).

Tutorials would also be welcome. The matplotlib documentation is rather confusing to me. When one searches something really specific, like rescaling a legend, different plot markers and colors and so on the official documentation is really precise but rather general information is not that good in my opinion. Too much different examples, no real explanations of the purposes...looks more or less like a big listing of all possible API methods and arguments.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#parts-of-a-figure is a good place to start.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`pyplot` is the 'scripting' level API in matplotlib (its highest level API to do a lot with matplotlib). It allows you to use matplotlib using a procedural interface in a similar way as you can do it with Matlab. `pyplot` has a notion of 'current figure' and 'current axes' that all the functions delegate to (@tacaswell dixit). So, when you use the functions available on the module `pyplot` you are plotting to the 'current figure' and 'current axes'.

If you want 'fine-grain' control of where/what your are plotting then you should use an object oriented API using instances of `Figure` and `Axes`.

Functions available in `pyplot` have an equivalent method in the `Axes`.

From the repo [anatomy of matplotlib](https://github.com/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib):

- The `Figure` is the top-level container in this hierarchy. It is the overall window/page that everything is drawn on. You can have multiple independent figures and `Figure`s can contain multiple Axes.

But...

- Most plotting occurs on an `Axes`. The axes is effectively the area that we plot data on and any ticks/labels/etc associated with it. Usually we'll set up an `Axes` with a call to subplot (which places `Axes` on a regular grid), so in most cases, `Axes` and `Subplot` are synonymous.
- Each `Axes` has an XAxis and a YAxis. These contain the ticks, tick locations, labels, etc.

If you want to know the anatomy of a plot you can visit this [link](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part1-Figures_Subplots_and_layouts.ipynb#Anatomy-of-a-%22Plot%22).

Comment: What did you mean by "*... and 'current axes' that all the functions delegate to (**@tacaswell dixit**).*"? I mean who/what is **@tacaswell dixit**? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Also, the last link to Jupyter nbviewer: "[Anatomy Of Matplotlib - Part1 - Figures_Subplots_and_layouts](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part1-Figures_Subplots_and_layouts.ipynb#Anatomy-of-a-%22Plot%22)" is really very helpful. Thank you so much for posting that here!

Answer (score 6):

I think that [this](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/) tutorial explains well the basic notions of the object hierarchy of matplotlib like Figure and Axes, as well as the notion of current figure and current Axes.

If you want a quick answer: There is the Figure object which is the container that wraps multiple Axes(which is different from axis) which also contains smaller objects like legends, line, tick marks ... as shown in this image taken from [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/examples/showcase/anatomy.html)

[image]

So when we do

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> type(fig)
<class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'>
>>> type(ax)
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```

We have created a Figure object and an Axes object that is contained in that figure.

Answer (score 1):

- `pyplot` is matlab like API for those who are familiar with matlab and want to make quick and dirty plots
- `figure` is object-oriented API for those who doesn't care about matlab style plotting

So you can use either one but perhaps not both together.

Comment: `pyplot` is implemented entirely in terms of the OO API, so you can mix-and-match.

Comment: So where's the difference between `pyplot` and `figure`? Is `pyplot` the entire window which pops up and `figure` just the image contained in the window?

Comment: In general, `pyplot` for iPython. `figure` for python script. Although you can mix and match, I don't find that very appealing.

Comment: `pyplot` is basically `figure` with some extra setting already added so that you can do `matlab` like plotting.

Comment: `pyplot` is a module, `Figure` is a class, most of the plotting methods are methods on the `Axes` class.  `pyplot` has a notion of 'current figure' and 'current axes' that all the functions delegate to.