# Why we use "gca" while we are ploting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

```
plt.pie(size,labels=columns)
p=plt.gcf()
p.gca().add_artist(my_graph)
plt.show()
```

I don't understand this code. Can anyone explain me ?

Comment: Did you try the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html)?

Comment: See also [matplotlib Axes.plot() vs pyplot.plot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482191/matplotlib-axes-plot-vs-pyplot-plot)

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()[source]
Get the current figure.

If no current figure exists, a new one is created using figure().
[click here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html)