# Display all values on a maplotlib barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame with 20 values, and I am trying to `bar.plot` it using `matplotlib`. when I do it, I am not seeing the 20 bars but 10. I have 5 nana values in it and 4 of them.
Here is a sample of dataframe:

```
Name             Bonus
Jack Carpenter   890
John Clegg       653
Mike Holiday     367
Rene Moukad      900
...........      ...
```

my code is standard:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,6))
plt.bar(df.Name, df.Bonus)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)
```

Comment: the code looks okay, pls add the rest of the values and also a screenshot of the graph you are getting.

Comment: Why do you specify `fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)` when the data on the x-axis is not a time series? Does it improve if I remove it?

Comment: Note that your code isn't standard:  you are mixing the pyplot interface with the object-oriented interface (see e.g. [matplotlib Axes.plot() vs pyplot.plot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482191/matplotlib-axes-plot-vs-pyplot-plot)).  You could use `ax.bar(df.Name, df.Bonus)`  and `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)`.  Are you using a recent matplotlib version?

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem reproducible from only the description. Could you provide a full reproducible example with test data?  Could you add the output of `df.Bonus.values` and `df.Name.values`?