# Circlify - change the colour of just one of the circles

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'Value': [10, 2, 23, 87, 12, 65]
})


circles = circlify.circlify(
    df['Value'].tolist(), 
    show_enclosure=False, 
    target_enclosure=circlify.Circle(x=0, y=0, r=1)
)

# Create just a figure and only one subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

# Title
ax.set_title('Basic circular packing')

# Remove axes
ax.axis('off')

# Find axis boundaries
lim = max(
    max(
        abs(circle.x) + circle.r,
        abs(circle.y) + circle.r,
    )
    for circle in circles
)
plt.xlim(-lim, lim)
plt.ylim(-lim, lim)

# list of labels
labels = df['Name']

# print circles
for circle, label in zip(circles, labels):
    x, y, r = circle
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((x, y), r, alpha=0.2, linewidth=2,color='#e6d4ff'))
    plt.annotate(
          label, 
          (x,y ) ,
          va='center',
          ha='center',
          size=12
     )
```

It produces this output:

[image]

I wanted to change the colour of just one of the circles (for example, the biggest circle).

I tried changing the colour from:

```
color='#e6d4ff'
```

to, for example, a list of colours:

```
color=['#e6d4ff','#e6d4ff','#e6d4ff','#e6d4ff','#e6d4ff','#ffc4c4']
```

with the error:

```
RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4
```

I guess the error is saying if I'm providing a list, then the list should just be RGB dimensions.

Would someone be able to show me? (I couldn't see it in the python graph gallery e.g. `[here][2]` or the circlify doc [here](https://pypi.org/project/circlify/) but maybe I've missed it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each call to `plt.Circle(...)` you're only creating one circle, which has only one color.  To assign different colors to different circles, the colors can be added into the `for` loop, e.g. : `for circle, label, color in zip(circles, labels, colors):`.

Note that `circlify` expects the list of values in sorted order, and that the returned list contains the circles sorted from smallest to largest. In your example code, `D` is the largest circle, but in your plot, you labeled it as `F`.  Sorting the dataframe at the start and using that order helps to keep values and labels synchronized.

Here is the example code, having `D` as largest and with a different color (the code also [changes a few `plt.` calls to `ax.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482191/matplotlib-axes-plot-vs-pyplot-plot) to be more consistent):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import circlify

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                   'Value': [10, 2, 23, 87, 12, 65]})
df = df.sort_values('Value')  # the order is now ['B', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'D']
circles = circlify.circlify(df['Value'].tolist(),
                            show_enclosure=False,
                            target_enclosure=circlify.Circle(x=0, y=0, r=1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

ax.set_title('Basic circular packing')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_aspect('equal')  # show circles as circles, not as ellipses

lim = max(max(abs(circle.x) + circle.r, abs(circle.y) + circle.r, )
          for circle in circles)
ax.set_xlim(-lim, lim)
ax.set_ylim(-lim, lim)

labels = df['Name']  # ['B', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'D']
colors = ['#ffc4c4' if val == df['Value'].max() else '#e6d4ff' for val in df['Value']]
for circle, label, color in zip(circles, labels, colors):
    x, y, r = circle
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((x, y), r, alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, color=color))
    ax.annotate(label, (x, y), va='center', ha='center', size=12)
plt.show()
```

[image: circle packing with largest circle in different color]