# how can i create a function to add titles and labels to my syntax

Tags: python, visualization

I am trying to write a user-defined function to add titles and labels to the syntax for a graph. This is what I am trying to do:

```
def mytitles(title,xvar,yvar):
```

in other to achieve this:

```
mytitles('title_name', 'xvar_name', 'yvar_name')
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with graph ? is it `matplotlib` plot? Can you give an example of you existing code?

Comment: Yes, a matplotlib plot

Comment: Existing code: 

plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

gun_trend = gun_clean.groupby(gun_clean.month.dt.year).totals.sum().plot()

plt.title('Gun Check Trend')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Totals in Millions')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1998,2017));

Comment: What i want: gun_clean.groupby(gun_clean.month.dt.year).totals.sum().plot(figsize=(14,8))
mytitles('Gun Check Trend', 'Years', 'Totals in Millions')

Comment: This looks like pandas plots.

Comment: Same applies here, you should get a figure or axis from pandas plot output, then you ll feed it to function.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please upvote/accept if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `matplotlib`, you need tou use:

- `ax.set_xlabel(label)` for x axis title
- `ax.set_ylabel(label)` for y axis title
- `ax.set_title(title)` for figure title

First you ll need to get either a figure or an ax object. Your function will act on them by calling the above methods.
For example, ill plot a simple plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = 2*np.arange(0, 3, .05)
y = np.sin(x)
figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
ax.plot(x,y)
```

If it is generated, like your case, with `pandas`, you'll need to do something similar to this:

```
figure = mydf.plot(x='x', y='y')
```

In my case `mydf` is created like this:

```
x = 2*np.arange(0, 3, .05)
y = np.sin(x)
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y })
```

Here, there only one axes since I want to plot only one plot in my figure. To get axes from figure object, I can do `figure.axes` and it contains a list of figure axes.

I can then define this function:

```
def add_text(fig, title, xlabel, ylabel):
    fig.axes[0].set_xlabel(xlabel)
    fig.axes[0].set_ylabel(ylabel)
    fig.axes[0].set_title(title)
    return fig
```

So to add title, xlabel and ylabel to my original figure, I can run this:

```
add_text(figure, 'mytile', 'myxlabel', 'myylabel')
```

Here, you can find more details about what are matplotlib objects:
[Understanding matplotlib: plt, figure, ax(arr)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677767/understanding-matplotlib-plt-figure-axarr)

Answer (score 0):

You might use this function

plt.title(f'$D_q$ curve at the parameter q={q}')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).